# Is there any way to set up a fake social graph of users and connections to test my app offline?

Tags: facebook, api

I'm working on an app that integrates with Facebook, but it relies a lot on what a user's friends are doing. Is there any way for me to simulate this? Is it possible to get my actual friends to connect with the app whilst it's still in developer mode?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some options-

- make the app **live**,
- create some test users in the app settings,
- add some friends as developers/testers in your app settings you can have access to the app which is still in development/sandbox mode.

You can read more here: [Managing Development Cycles](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/bestpractice/managing-development-cycle)